# How to make a Windows Explorer Window appear in a kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy-language

I am making an app in python alongside kvlang and I want to have a popup windows explorer window appear for user to select a path. Kind of like in Discord when you're sending someone a file:

[image]

Now I haven't found a way online to do this which makes me wonder if this is even an option. So my questions are: "Is there an option like this?" and "If there is, how do I do this?". Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tkinter [tkinter file dialog](https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-filedialog/#:%7E:text=File%20dialogs%20help%20you%20open,has%20the%20customer%20tk%20style.) alongside kivy.

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks!

Comment: One question though, It works but I do get this little white tkinter window, how do I make it disappear?

Comment: @GetTwoBirdsStonedAtOnce you can't, but what you can do is make it really small! This is the code you need: tk.geometry("0x0"). Also replace tk with the name of the variable that you have Tk() linked with

Comment: Hey, Sorry for replying so late, but I got it working with this simple line of code:
Tk.Tk().withdraw()